# Trying to fix this Python code for hangman but failing to do so

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this hangman code to work. It's supposed to take a random word from the random words array and assign that to guessword. This part works.

However, when a letter is inputted, right or wrong, it will print out

```
 print("This letter is not in the word")
            print("You have", str(lives), "lives left")
```

this part. Furthermore when I print out the values of guessword and randomletters, guessword is a string while randomletters is an array. How do I make it so that this prints correctly and the code properly runs?
The full code is below

```
import random  # Random function

# Defines the game as a function
from typing import List


def hangman():
    lives = 6  # Lives counter
    entered_words = []  # Array for user input
    userletters = []  # Used for letters that have been inputted
    rndwords: List[str] = ["pumpkin", "red", "animal", "chocolate", "peas"]  # Words
    userletters: list

    # Code to ask the user if they want to add words to the array
    userinput = input("Add word: (y/n)")
    if userinput == "y":
        a = str(input("What word would you like to add?"))
        rndwords.append(a)
        print(a, "has been added")
    elif userinput == "n":
        print("Ok")
    else:
        print("Enter (y/n)")

    # Picks a word randomly from the array
    random_num = random.randint(0, (len(rndwords) - 1))
    guessword: list
    guessword = rndwords[random_num].lower()  # Picks a random word from the array
    print("The word is ", str(len(guessword)), "letters long")
    print("\n")
    c = "_ " * len(guessword)
    print(c)
    guessword: list
    # Checks if a correct character has been inputted
    while lives != 0:
        guess = input(print("Guess a letter: "))  # Asks user for input
        for i in range(0, 1):
            if guess in guessword:
                entered_words.append(i)
                print("This letter is in the word")
                userletters.append(i)
            else:
                pass

        if guessword[i] != guess:
            userletters.append(guess)
            lives = lives - 1
            print("This letter is not in the word")
            print("You have", str(lives), "lives left")

        if list(guessword) == userletters or list(guessword) == guess:
            print("You have won, good job")
            return
        # Ends the game when lives counter reaches 0
        if lives == 0:
            print("You have lost")
            print("The word is", guessword)
            print(guessword)
            print(userletters)
            return


hangman()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in this code,

Firstly, you made a mistake while getting user input

```
input(print("Guess a letter: "))
```

this statement always prints an extra `None`, what you should have done was

```
input("Guess a letter: ")
```

Secondly, you ask user if he/she wants to enter a char but you are not doing correct thing when they answers `no`, you continue asking letters. Maybe you should add a `return` statement there.

Thirdly, if you add following code in your program and debug, you can see your algorithm actually works

```
guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
print(f"guess {guess}")
print(guessword)
```

the main problem is in the following part, this statement is not working

```
if guessword[i] != guess:
    userletters.append(guess)
    lives = lives - 1
    print("This letter is not in the word")
    print("You have", str(lives), "lives left")
```

with `guessword[i] != guess` statement you are clearly always checking first element of guessword, which is clearly wrong.

what you should do is deleting the `for` loop, which is currently doing nothing, adding an `integer i` before the while and increase it at the and of the loop.

Comment: How exactly do I implement the i = i + 1 bit and how do i get it to have an impact on the code? I assigned it before the while: `i : int
    i = 0
    while lives != 0:` but I'm not sure where to add that. Also what do I replace the guessword != guess with?